# detox tests not recognising View even after adding id

Tags: react-native, detox

Apologies in advance if this has been asked before. I came across the `detox`  e2e framework for react native apps, and I thought of giving it a try.

I am trying to automate this demo mobile application given here - [link](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten-demo-app)
Since the tests in `detox` uses `testID` as one of the locators so I added one in the `LoginScreenMaterial.js` file inside `app/screen/LoginScreenMaterial.js` like this

```
<View testID="login_screen" style={{width: this._width, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <RkCard style={styles.container}>
            <View rkCardHeader style={styles.header}>
              <RkText/>
              <RkText style={styles.label}>Sign in into your account</RkText>
            </View>
```

However, even after sucessfully building the app, I ran the app with this simple test

```
it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('login_screen'))).toBeVisible();
  });
```

However, the tests still fail with the element being failed to be recognised. What am I missing here in this tests? Can we not add `testID` like this explicitly in the `.js` file.

Edit 1 : Adding the error message

```
1) Example
       should have welcome screen:
     Error: Error: Cannot find UI Element.
Exception with Assertion: {
  "Assertion Criteria" : "assertWithMatcher:matcherForSufficientlyVisible(>=0.750000)",
  "Element Matcher" : "(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('login_screen')) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('login_screen')) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))",
  "Recovery Suggestion" : "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
}

Error Trace: [
  {
    "Description" : "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
    "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
    "Error Code" : "0",
    "File Name" : "GREYElementInteraction.m",
    "Function Name" : "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
    "Line" : "124"
  }
]
      at Client.execute (node_modules/detox/src/client/Client.js:74:13)
```

Comment: can you include the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: @vonovak see the edit please. Thanks!

Comment: The demo app is extremely old and you don't say what version of detox you're using. I'd first try visual inspector in xcode so you see your view hierarchy or upgrade to RN 0.55 and latest detox.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took a look at the application and was able to get it to work. I set the following in my devDependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "jest": "23.2.0",
    "detox": "8.0.0"
    ...
  },
```

To the package.json I also added

```
"detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoomApp.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/BoomApp.xcodeproj -scheme BoomApp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 7"
      }
    },
```

I ran `detox init -r jest`

I was then able to get it to recognise when a specific screen had been rendered I did this by adding the testID to the ScrollView LoginScreenBlur.js (line 23)

```
<AppWrapper>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} testID={'login_screen'}>
    ....
    </ScrollView>
</AppWrapper>
```

A then in `e2e/firstTest.spec.js` I replaced the tests with

```
  it('should have loginScreen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('login_screen'))).toBeVisible();
  });
```

This was my console response after running `detox build && detox test`

```
node_modules/.bin/jest e2e --config=e2e/config.json --maxWorkers=1 --testNamePattern='^((?!:android:).)*$'
 server listening on localhost:64579...
 : Searching for device matching iPhone 7...
 : Uninstalling org.reactjs.native.example.BoomApp...
 : org.reactjs.native.example.BoomApp uninstalled
 : Installing /Users/work/Downloads/react-native-ui-kitten-demo-app-master/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoomApp.app...
 : /Users/work/Downloads/react-native-ui-kitten-demo-app-master/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoomApp.app installed
 : Terminating org.reactjs.native.example.BoomApp...
 : org.reactjs.native.example.BoomApp terminated
 : Launching org.reactjs.native.example.BoomApp...
7: org.reactjs.native.example.BoomApp launched. The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F /Users/work/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AF406169-5CF3-4480-9D00-8F934C420043/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err}
 PASS  e2e/firstTest.spec.js (7.935s)
  Example
    ✓ should have loginScreen (1499ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.87s, estimated 9s
Ran all test suites matching /e2e/i with tests matching "^((?!:android:).)*$".
```

It would seem that the app defaults to launching LoginScreenBlur, so it would make sense to test it first, rather than LoginScreenMaterial.

One thing I have noticed is that the application uses `RKTextInput` and `RkButton`, these are not native components but wrappers around native components. This means that you will need to pass the testID down to the native component that you want to have the testID. I am not sure if `react-native-ui-kitten` supports accessibility labels, so there may be some more work ahead if you wish to automate input of text and button taps.

**Adding testID to custom components**

See Step 3 https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.WritingFirstTest.md

> Note that not all React components support this prop. Most of the built-in native components in React Native like View, Text, TextInput, Switch, ScrollView have support though. If you create your own composite components, you will have to propagate this prop manually to the correct native component.

A more detailed explanation of adding testID to custom components is given here https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.RunningTests.md#cant-find-my-component-even-though-i-added-testid-to-its-props

Briefly you should implement your custom component as follows.

**Custom Component**

```
export class MyCompositeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity testID={this.props.testID}>
        <View>
          <Text>Something something</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

**Using Custom Component**

Then you should use it like this.

```
render() {
  return <MyCompositeComponent testID='MyUniqueId123' />;
}
```

**Searching the hierarchy**

If you have done the above and you are sure your item has the correct testID and the tests are still failing, then you can search for it in the view hierarchy  https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting/running-tests.md#debug-view-hierarchy

I won't repeat the above post in full but the steps are

1. Start a debuggable app (not a release build) in your simulator
2. Open Xcode
3. Attach Xcode to your app's process
4. Press the Debug View Hierarchy button
5. This will open the hierarchy viewer, and will show a breakdown of your app's native view hierarchy. Here you can browse through the views
6. React Native testIDs are manifested as accessibility identifiers in the native view hierarchy

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation. I would surely try this one out-regarding the custom components. Nicely put in this answer.

Comment: I tried this today but facing the same error - in the first test. I tried installing jest and detox to versions that you have but I am unable to do so. Is this the reason?

Comment: @demouser123 that is frustrating. I decided to fork your repo and create a branch with the changes. You can see it [here](https://github.com/andrewmarmion/react-native-ui-kitten-demo-app/tree/detox_test). Download my fork, switch to branch **detox_test**, `npm i`, `watchman watch-del-all`, close the metro bundler if you have it open, then run `detox build && detox test`. Hopefully that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use AccessiblityLabel to add ID to the View Element:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html

Comment: Can you edit and give a short example on how to do it. Would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this accessibilityLabel is gonna be your testID which will be recognized in your testing tools:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  accessible={true}
  accessibilityLabel={'Tap me!'}
  onPress={this._onPress}>
  <View style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Press me!</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```